# JSONPath filter by date

Tags: json

If you have JSON data with date as key for the json objects, can you use json path to filter data by date range?

For example in the sample below get all the book titles with pubdate between x and y dates.

````
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "pubdate": '02/10/1994'
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "pubdate": '02/10/1993'
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "pubdate": '02/10/1992'
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "pubdate": '02/10/1991'
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The incantation depends on the software used to parse the JSON.